# Ant design - Select overwrite dropdown menu position

Tags: antd

I have a Select component with a a few options.Right under the Select menu I have a button. Because of the button when I click on the Select to prevent overlap my dropdown menu automatically goes to the top the component. I want to have an overlap, but I don't know how to set a placement of bottomCenter for dropdown in Select. Is it possible to do that without fully overwriting the dropdownRender? Thank you.

My code

```
return (
    <Select mode="multiple" allowClear style={{ width: '100%'}} 
           placeholder="Search here" onChange={handleChange}> 
        {children}
     </Select>
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this prop: `dropdownAlign={{ offset: [-40, 4] }}`

Comment: not documented anywhere

Comment: @NitsanBaleli antd select is based on rc-select so all the props that are listet here can be applied: https://github.com/react-component/select

Comment: thanks. it's helped me a lot because it's still unavailable in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For recent version of ant design Dropdown prop should be `align={{ offset: [-40, 4] }}` 
 It's not in the document but could be found [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/dropdown/dropdown.tsx)